# How can I identify the wifi chip form factor?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, motherboard, chipset

The wifi card in my laptop is old and no longer connects to many networks in the wild.

I would like to replace it but I can’t find how to shop for the correct form factor.

On the bottom of the connection, it says "A05-04":

[image]

Unfortunately, plugging into Google does not give me any results to find what the name of the form factor is, nor any matching wifi cards I can replace it with.

Comment: What's your laptop model?

Comment: @JourneymanGeek I _think_ it's the "Legion Y740" from Lenovo.

Comment: Ah! We have a problem there. I'll post a fuller answer

Comment: Rather than installing an internal WiFi card, which appears to be problematic, it might be easier to use an external USB WiFi adapter, available for US$10 and up. It might even improve range, since some have antennas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before you do anything, its worth taking into account that there's a few 'pitfalls' and non standard things in wifi adaptors.

I googled the model of the card - while the 'killer 1550i' has no interesting hits, the corresponding intel model (Killer cards are normal wifi cards with additional firmware and driver changes these days) [gives you some information](https://www.intel.sg/content/www/xa/en/products/sku/99446/intel-wirelessac-9560/specifications.html)

Some brands (notably lenovo/thinkpad) have whitelists for allowed wifi adaptors. Upgrading those models is fraught. With that out of the way, I *believe* this is a [CNVi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CNVi) type adaptor on a m.2 physical adaptor.

*This* is a problem. Even though its M.2, and if you got a CNVi adaptor, Lenovo locks down firmware, and unless you get a modded bios (dangerous, and out of the scope of this question), you're restricted to specific models with *lenovo supported firmware* when upgrading, and their parts page has no options other than the one you have.

Essentially, you really have no options in upgrading 'easily', even knowing what type of wifi card it is.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what does "A05-04" represent? There seem to be different codes among the cnvi m.2 chips.

Comment: Good question and... I have no idea.

Comment: @SlavaKnyazev - It likely does not represent anything. The form factor is NGFF Mini PCI Express.  I was able to identify it.  I also verified this factor by searching eBay and backported the information to Wikipedia to check the layout of the pins.

Comment: @Ramhound that its a PC with a whitelist is a 'bigger' problem, and yeah, that's the same train of thought I followed :D

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - If it's anything, it would be a board revision number; it's very strange that a card like this just ceases to work and should work since it's an 802.11ac card

Comment: Well yeah, but that's also out of the scope of the question :D

Comment: Thank you! You correctly identified the connection type, but the whitelisting issue didn't happen. I swapped it out for a "Intel AX200NGW" and it's working great.

Comment: That's a pleasant surprise - and one time I am glad to be wrong